# android debug environment variables

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

Trying to figure out how to pass information from Eclipse to my Android app.  Basically, in code I have a variable that is the hostname of my server.  However, for debugging purposes, I want to point at my local machine instead of a production server; I don't want to change this file so that I don't accidentally commit it (i.e. I want to give myself & other devs on my team the ability to override various configuration at runtime).  Normally you could do this via environment variables, but I can't figure out how to do that for Android.

Is there a way to do this (or something equivalent) where I can specify configuration when I launch the debug instance.

Comment: please clear your question with some code or examples..!

Answer (score 5):

in case anyone was wondering, I added an xml file into the res directory. Then I utilize reflection to look into R to find the id by name & then get the string value from the context.

So for example I put the following XML into `res/values/dev.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="server">myserver.mydomain.com</string>
    <string name="username">myusername</string>
    <string name="password">mypassword</string>
</resources>
```

Then I use reflection to find the Id of `R.strings.server` & do `<context>.getString(id)`